# Removing None-Using Resolutions from display list

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

My Monitor's highest resolution is 1600x900. But I can see some other resolutions after the highest one on the list. If I select one of them, the display will be out of the band. till now there is no problem because I will not select them.

But I always have trouble with games, most of the games will select the highest resolution from the list automatically and they will be out of the band and I can not fix them. So how can I remove those extra and none-using resolutions from the display list?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "out of the band"? If the display driver publishes these resolutions, it is because it can display them.

Comment: @harrymc maybe the monitor can not handle them.

Comment: Do you mean that at those resolutions the display is larger or smaller than the screen?

Comment: @harrymc yes, those resolutions are larger than the screen.

Comment: Could you add to the post the models of your computer, monitor and display adapter?